# Identifying repetition of characters using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to find repetitions of individual character, where the character repeats for 3 or more times. `"444"`, `"sss"`, and `"------"` should be identified, while `"dd"` should not be identified.

I came across a previous StackOverflow question which gave the solution as:

```
regexp = re.compile(r"(.)\1")
```

However, this identifies 2 or more repetitions of the same character.
I tried `(r"(.)\{3,}")` which does not work, and `(r"(.)\3")` which gives an error.
Can somebody please give me the correct regex for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `(r"(.)\1\1")` (or even `(r"(.)\1\1+")`).

The regex is "match any character (`.`), then match that same character again (`\1`), then match that same character a third time (for the first variant I've got here) or match that same character one or more additional times (for the second variant above).

Comment: I tried your regex with st = "111" in the following way `re.findall(r"(.)\1\1",st)` but my output was `['1']` instead of `['111']`. why like this?

Comment: @RanRag: That's because the parentheses are around the first character only. Use `(r"(.{3,})")` if you need to capture the whole thing.

Comment: Does Python not support `(r"(.)\1{2,}")`?